# What is SOAP now an acronym for?

Tags: web-services, soap

SOAP was once an acronym for 'Simple Object Access Protocol', but I believe this changed when SOAP became a standard.

Wikipedia doesn't state what it now stands for.

What is it now an acronym for?

Comment: Technically it should be FSP: Firewall Subversion Protocol

Comment: Here you have **ALL** meanings of SOAP: http://www.acronymfinder.com/SOAP.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't. [From the spec:](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#intro)

> In previous versions of this specification the SOAP name was an acronym. This is no longer the case.

Actually, it was still an acronym for the 1.1 standard; that changed with 1.2.

Comment: I suspect they couldn't, in all good conscience, keep the word "simple" to describe what SOAP has become.

Comment: @skaffman: It could *never* have been simple; it violates [Fowler's First Law of Distributed Object Design](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/FirstLaw.html).

Comment: Is this like when `SUN` used to stand for `Stanford University Network` but that changed to it just being the word Sun?  In that case should you call it `Soap` and not `SOAP`?

Comment: Good point. But then to me, Soap is something you wash yourself with ;) In other words, it becomes a noun, not an acronym.